# When I use storm trident, if I set the parallelism not less than 2, how can I make all the executors run on different servers not just on one server?

Tags: apache-storm, trident

i.e., if the parallelism is 2, the bolt run on 2 different servers, and if the parallelism is 3, the bolt run on 3 different servers. It's important for me, for I don't want all the tasks running on just one server, that'll be too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to increase configuration parameter "number of workers" (default value is 1) via

```
Config cfg = new Config();
cfg.setNumWorkers(...);
```

You can also limit the number of workers per host via storm.yaml config parameter `supersior.slots.ports` -- for each port, one worker JVM can be started, thus if you only provide one port for this config, only one worker JVM will get started. Just be aware, that this might limit the number of topologies you can run. A single worker JVM will only execute code from a single topology (to isolate topologies from each other).

Comment: Thanks. Actually I did just as you say, but I find for some bolts, even I set the number of workers more than 1 and set the parallelism of the bolts more than 1, one bolt just starts up several processes on only one server... What's wrong about it?

Comment: Extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks, is that the only way to do this? For I think it's better that we do not limit the slot number per host and meanwhile we make the executors run on different servers:)

Comment: You can also provide an custom scheduler. https://github.com/xumingming/storm-lib/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/DemoScheduler.java and https://github.com/xumingming/storm-lib/blob/master/src/jvm/storm/DemoScheduler.java